# Symfony 3 DateType year format

Tags: php, html, symfony, doctrine

Hi I've got a problem with year format on DateType, let take a look on this image
[image: Example image]

I want to change year from AD convert to BE in Thailand format

So It's will look like this AD = 2017 convert to BE = 2560

Is anyone know how to change this thing

and this is my form type code.

```
->add('birthday', DateType::class, [
 'required' => false,
 'widget' => 'single_text',
 'label' => 'Birthdate',
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely want to use an external plugin to manage this as the Symfony default won't handle conversion of "base year."

Something like this will be where I'd look: https://github.com/jojosati/bootstrap-datepicker-thai/blob/thai/README-thai.md

And then in your builder object, I'd add a class to select the thai datepicker elements:

```
$builder->add('birthday', 'text', array( 
    'attr'   =>  array(
        'class'   => 'thai-datepicker') //for example
    )
);
```

Comment: I'm just beginner in coding I don't know how to use that bootstrap-datepicker-thai Can you explain how to use step by step ?

Comment: The docs for the package are actually very well written. I'd recommend reading this page first, and then leveraging the page I linked above: https://github.com/jojosati/bootstrap-datepicker-thai